# Recursively Transform my JSON data with JS

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, tree, transform

I'm trying to figure out how to transform some JSON i'm getting back from a web service so i can easily parse it into a nice type-safe object. I want to transform this format from:

```
[{
        "name": "AwesomePeople",
        "value": [
            [{
                    "name": "TypeId",
                    "value": 1
                }, {
                    "name": "People",
                    "value": [

                        [{
                                "name": "id",
                                "value": 2
                            }, {
                                "name": "name",
                                "value": "Danno"
                            }
                        ],
                        [{
                                "name": "id",
                                "value": 3
                            }, {
                                "name": "name",
                                "value": "Julio"
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ],
            [{
                    "name": "TypeId",
                    "value": 2
                }, {
                    "name": "People",
                    "value": [
                        [{
                                "name": "id",
                                "value": 4
                            }, {
                                "name": "name",
                                "value": "Jenna"
                            }
                        ],
                        [{
                                "name": "id",
                                "value": 5
                            }, {
                                "name": "name",
                                "value": "Coolio"
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

To the following format:

```
[{
        "AwesomePeople": [
            [{
                    "TypeId": 1,
                }, {
                    "People": [

                        [{
                                "id": 2
                            }, {
                                "firstName":"Danno"
                            }
                        ],
                        [{
                                "id": 3,
                            }, {
                                "firstName": "Julio"
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ],
            [{
                    "TypeId": 2
                }, {
                    "People": [
                        [{
                                "id": 4
                            }, {
                                "firstName": "Jenna"
                            }
                        ],
                        [{
                                "id": 5
                            }, {
                                "firstName": "Coolio"
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
];
```

Two main things need to happen, these stupid "name"/"value" pairs need to be swapped at any and all levels. For example, instead of "name": "id", "value": "3", it would be simply be "id":3. The values are sometimes are arrays, so they need to processed in a similar way...the depth is variable, so i can't assume a certain number of levels deep, so i need to keep processing everything recursively.

I have started playing with the following code...you'll see an empty "newResult" array that i'm trying to build as i traverse the original JSON, taking different action whether i'm currently looking at an object, an array, or a key/property.

```
let count = 0;
let result = <the original array above>
let newResult = [];
 result.forEach(function(resObj) {
   console.log("STARTING to TRAVERSE HIGHER LEVEL OBJECTS!");
    traverse(resObj);
   count++;
   
   //we're done processing high level objects, so return from this function and enjoy the newResult!
   if (count===result.length) 
     //return from this function
     console.log(newResult);
       console.log("FINISHED PROCESSING HIGHER LEVEL OBJECTS, SO DONE!");
   
  });


//Below are the functions for traversing 
function traverse(x, level) {
  if (isArray(x)) {
    console.log("array");
    traverseArray(x);
  } else if ((typeof x === 'object') && (x !== null)) {
    console.log("object");
    traverseObject(x);
  } else {
     console.log("property: "+x);
     //console.log(level + x);
  }
}

function isArray(o) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(o) === '[object Array]';
}

function traverseArray(arr, level) {
  //console.log(level + "<array>");
  arr.forEach(function(x) {
    traverse(x);
  });
}

function traverseObject(obj, level) {
  var keyName, keyValue;
  //console.log(level + "<object>");
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if (key==="name"){
        keyName = obj[key];
        
      }else if (key==="value"){
        keyValue = obj[key];
      }
      if (keyName && keyValue){
        var newObj = {[keyName]: keyValue}
        newResult.push(newObj);
        //console.log("the KEY NAME IS: "+ keyName + ", and the VALUE is: "+keyValue);
      }
      //if we have a key value, but the value is an array, stop and 
     // if (isArray(newOj)
      console.log("traversing..." +obj[key]);
      
      traverse(obj[key]);
    }//end if property
  }//end foreach key in object
  
}//end traverseObject
```

thanks all...kudos to the person who can get their brain around this :)

Comment: by the way, the discrepancy in the code samples above...my bad, i was trying not to confuse people between the "name" key and the actual "name" value...so but i only renamed it to "firstName" in the second code block. @CertainPerformance didn't seem to be phased by that. thx!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` - with a reviver, check if the value has a `name` property, and if it does, return `{ [value.name]: value.value }`:

```js
const arr=[{name:"AwesomePeople",value:[[{name:"TypeId",value:1},{name:"People",value:[[{name:"id",value:2},{name:"name",value:"Danno"}],[{name:"id",value:3},{name:"name",value:"Julio"}]]}],[{name:"TypeId",value:2},{name:"People",value:[[{name:"id",value:4},{name:"name",value:"Jenna"}],[{name:"id",value:5},{name:"name",value:"Coolio"}]]}]]}];

const result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr, (key, value) => (
  value?.name
    ? { [value.name]: value.value }
    : value
)));
console.log(result);
```

If you also want to change the `name` values to `firstName` keys, add a conditional in the computed property:

```js
const arr=[{name:"AwesomePeople",value:[[{name:"TypeId",value:1},{name:"People",value:[[{name:"id",value:2},{name:"name",value:"Danno"}],[{name:"id",value:3},{name:"name",value:"Julio"}]]}],[{name:"TypeId",value:2},{name:"People",value:[[{name:"id",value:4},{name:"name",value:"Jenna"}],[{name:"id",value:5},{name:"name",value:"Coolio"}]]}]]}];

const result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr, (key, value) => (
  value?.name
    ? { [value.name === 'name' ? 'firstName' : value.name]: value.value }
    : value
)));
console.log(result);
```

Manually:

```js
const arr=[{name:"AwesomePeople",value:[[{name:"TypeId",value:1},{name:"People",value:[[{name:"id",value:2},{name:"name",value:"Danno"}],[{name:"id",value:3},{name:"name",value:"Julio"}]]}],[{name:"TypeId",value:2},{name:"People",value:[[{name:"id",value:4},{name:"name",value:"Jenna"}],[{name:"id",value:5},{name:"name",value:"Coolio"}]]}]]}];

const recurse = (val) => {
  if (!val || typeof val !== 'object') return val;
  if (Array.isArray(val)) return val.map(recurse);
  return { [val.name === 'name' ? 'firstName' : val.name]: val.value };
};


const result = recurse(arr);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wow, i was totally over thinking it i guess. Excellent job sir.

Answer (score 0):

I grabbed your data, quickly wrote a function to convert it, came to post it and realized that my output wasn't at all what you requested.  I would just throw it away, except that it seems to me this output is much more useful than what you requested.  So if you can use something like this:

```js
{
  AwesomePeople: [
    {
      TypeId: 1,
      People: [
        {id: 2, name: "Danno"},
        {id: 3, name: "Julio"}
      ]
    },
    {
      TypeId: 2,
      People: [
        {id: 4, name: "Jenna"},
        {id: 5, name: "Coolio"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

then this function may help:

```js
const convert = (xs) =>
  Object .fromEntries (
    xs .map (({name, value}) => [
      name, 
      Array .isArray (value) ? value .map (convert) : value
    ])
  )

const data = [{name: "AwesomePeople", value: [[{name: "TypeId", value: 1}, {name: "People", value: [[{name: "id", value: 2}, {name: "name", value: "Danno"}], [{name: "id", value: 3}, {name: "name", value: "Julio"}]]}], [{name: "TypeId", value: 2}, {name: "People", value: [[{name: "id", value: 4}, {name: "name", value: "Jenna"}], [{name: "id", value: 5}, {name: "name", value: "Coolio"}]]}]]}]

console .log (convert (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

If not, well then maybe someone else might get some use out of it.

Comment: Scott, actually your format is actually what i wanted...but i didn't know it at the time...!!!! this code allows me to do a JSON.parse(object) as IMyInterface[]....very nice :).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). This code modifies the original input, which can be significantly faster than rebuilding the structure.

Note that in your input the data is a bit inconsistent: Where does `firstName` come from? So I've assumed consistency

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = [{ name: 'AwesomePeople', value: [ [{ name: 'TypeId', value: 1 }, { name: 'People', value: [ [{ name: 'id', value: 2 }, { name: 'name', value: 'Danno' } ], [{ name: 'id', value: 3 }, { name: 'name', value: 'Julio' } ] ] } ], [{ name: 'TypeId', value: 2 }, { name: 'People', value: [ [{ name: 'id', value: 4 }, { name: 'name', value: 'Jenna' } ], [{ name: 'id', value: 5 }, { name: 'name', value: 'Coolio' } ] ] } ] ] } ];

objectScan(['**[*].name'], {
  filterFn: ({ parent }) => {
    const { name, value } = parent;
    delete parent.name;
    delete parent.value;
    parent[name] = value;
  }
})(data);

console.log(data);
// => [ { AwesomePeople: [ [ { TypeId: 1 }, { People: [ [ { id: 2 }, { name: 'Danno' } ], [ { id: 3 }, { name: 'Julio' } ] ] } ], [ { TypeId: 2 }, { People: [ [ { id: 4 }, { name: 'Jenna' } ], [ { id: 5 }, { name: 'Coolio' } ] ] } ] ] } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@14.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)